# Better way to replace items in a list / dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, list-comprehension

I have to manually correct some data that may be misleading for a model otherwise.

the logic is :

```
    if col("a") not empty & col("b") negative 
    => create col("ret_a") = 2*min(col("a")) - col("a")
    else col("ret_a") = col("a")
```

The code i'm using and which does the job (but is not pretty) is :

```
# a
df["ret_a"] = np.where(
    np.logical_and(pd.notnull(df["a"]), df["b"] < 0),
    2*df["a"].min()- df["a"],
    df["a"])
```

The issue is that i have a bunch of conditions... and I don't think a condition like "<0" can be stored in a dict{} to use pd.map()

I then tried to build something using :

```
df['i'] = np.select(conditions, choices,)
```

with 'i' 'conditions' and 'choices':

```
i= [
    'RETURN_COM_EQY_',                     # a
    'INTEREST_COVERAGE_RATIO_',            # b
    'TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_CAP_',                # c
    'TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY_',                # d
    'NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_',                 # e
    'NET_INTEREST_COVERAGE_']              # f

conditions = [
    (df['TOTAL_EQUITY_'] < 0),            # a
    (df['IS_INT_EXPENSE_'] < 0),          # b
    (df['NET_DEBT_'] < 0),                # c
    (df['NET_DEBT_'] < 0),                # d
    (df['NET_DEBT_'] < 0),                # e1
    (df['EBIT_'] < 0),                    # e2
    (df['IS_INT_EXPENSE_'] < 0)]          # f

choices = [
    2*df["RETURN_COM_EQY_"].min() - df["RETURN_COM_EQY_"],                         # a
    2*df["INTEREST_COVERAGE_RATIO_"].min() - df["INTEREST_COVERAGE_RATIO_"],       # b
    2*df["TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_CAP_"].max() - df["TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_CAP_"],               # c
    2*df["TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY_"].max() - df["TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY_"],               # d
    2*df["NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"].max() - df["NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"],                 # e1
    2*df["NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"].min() - df["NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"],                 # e2
    2*df["NET_INTEREST_COVERAGE_"].min() - df["NET_INTEREST_COVERAGE_"],           # f
    ]
```

the complete code for that operation would be :

```
    # a
df["ret_mean_RETURN_COM_EQY_"] = np.where(
    np.logical_and(pd.notnull(df["mean_RETURN_COM_EQY_"]),
                   df["mean_TOTAL_EQUITY_"] < 0),
    2*df["mean_RETURN_COM_EQY_"].min() 
    - df["mean_RETURN_COM_EQY_"],
                   df["mean_RETURN_COM_EQY_"])

# b
df["ret_mean_INTEREST_COVERAGE_RATIO_"] = np.where(
    np.logical_and(pd.notnull(df["mean_INTEREST_COVERAGE_RATIO_"]),
                   df["mean_IS_INT_EXPENSE_"] < 0),
    2*df["mean_INTEREST_COVERAGE_RATIO_"].min() 
    - df["mean_INTEREST_COVERAGE_RATIO_"],
                   df["mean_INTEREST_COVERAGE_RATIO_"])
# c
df["ret_mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_CAP_"] = np.where(
    np.logical_and(pd.notnull(df["mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_CAP_"]),
                   df["mean_NET_DEBT_"] < 0),
    2*df["mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_CAP_"].max()
    - df["mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_CAP_"],
                   df["mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_CAP_"])

# d
df["ret_mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY_"] = np.where(
    np.logical_and(pd.notnull(df["mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY_"]),
                   df["mean_NET_DEBT_"] < 0),
    2*df["mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY_"].max()
    - df["mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY_"],
                   df["mean_TOT_DEBT_TO_TOT_EQY_"])

# e1
df["ret_mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"] = np.where(
    np.logical_and(pd.notnull(df["mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"]),
                   df["mean_NET_DEBT_"] < 0),
    2*df["mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"].max()
    - df["mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"],
                   df["mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"])

# e2
df["ret_mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"] = np.where(
    np.logical_and(pd.notnull(df["mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"]),
                   df["mean_EBIT_"] < 0),
    2*df["mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"].min()
    - df["mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"],
                   df["ret_mean_NET_DEBT_TO_EBITDA_"]) # different here

# f
df["ret_mean_NET_INTEREST_COVERAGE_"] = np.where(
    np.logical_and(pd.notnull(df["mean_NET_INTEREST_COVERAGE_"]),
                   df["mean_IS_INT_EXPENSE_"] < 0),
    2*df["mean_NET_INTEREST_COVERAGE_"].min()
    - df["mean_NET_INTEREST_COVERAGE_"],
                   df["mean_NET_INTEREST_COVERAGE_"])
```

Comment: "does the job (but is not pretty)" I clearly have beer goggles :P What do you think is wrong with that? I think the problem overall is interesting, I'm just curious what you think is wrong with that specifically?

Comment: It was tedious as hell to do the first time (which is unpythonic ? :p). As this seems like common data management task, someone must have a better solution somewhere => FOMO !

Comment: I think the overall task is beyond me in getting an elegant solution, I look forward to what you get as an answer. But I really don't think your approach is unpythonic (numpy and pandas have a different standard)

Comment: Just store your column names in a list of tuples `[('a_1', 'b_1'), ('a_2, 'b_2), ...]` and since that calculation is identical, just write the calculation once and iterate through the tuples.

Comment: @ALollz, Indeed I can do that since I'm always checking the same condition... ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do the job:

```
def func(df, i_n, condition, choice):
   name = "ret_" + i_n
   df[name] = df[i_n]
   df.loc[(pd.notnull(df[i_n])) & (condition), name] = choice

for i_n, condition, choice in zip(i, conditions, choices):
   func(df, i_n, condition, choice)
```

Comment: I like the Idea. I'm getting "Exception has occurred: TypeError
'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'" when passing the condition through the function

Comment: This may happen because some values in the dataframe aren't integers, try for example df['TOTAL_EQUITY_'].astype(float) < 0

Comment: Glad it helped!